# Whats is the relationship between energy of an atom and its magnetic moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, dipole-moment

I'm working on a problem that says that

> If $\varepsilon_{\pm}=\mp (\mu \mu_0 H + k \theta \frac{M}{\mu N} )$ is the energy of the atom of a specimen that can orient itself either parallel or antiparallel in a magnetic field, show that $ \frac{M}{\mu N}= tanh(\frac{1}{kT}( \mu \mu_0 H + k \theta \frac{M}{\mu N}))$.

I'm not really sure how the energy would relate to its magnetic moment. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic moment is $\mu$. You are told how it relates: if it is parallel to the magnetic field then the energy is presumably $\epsilon_+ = -\dots$ whereas if it is antiparallel then the energy is presumably $\epsilon_- = +\dots$.

As evidenced by the "thermodynamic beta" $1/(k_\text B T)$ this is a thermodynamics problem of weighting certain outcomes with Boltzmann factors due to them being in the [canonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble) (constant number of particles in thermal equilibrium with a reservoir at a constant temperature $T$). The total magnetization $M$ is $\mu$ times the number of particles which are spin-parallel minus $\mu$ times the number of particles which are spin-antiparallel. These will be $N$ times the probability of being parallel or antiparallel, and those probabilities will come by weighting each possibility with energy $E$ by its Boltzmann factor $e^{-E/(k_\text B T)}$ and then dividing by the total weight (which is called the "partition function").

The combination $\frac{e^{a} - e^{-a}}{e^a + e^{-a}}$ can be rewritten as ${\sinh a \over\cosh a} = \tanh a$ with the use of the hyperbolic trigonometric functions.

Comment: I'm trying my best to understand but unfortunately I'm struggling :/ the way I reasoned this problem was to show how $\frac{\mu B}{kt} = \frac{1}{kT}(\mu \mu_0 + k\theta \frac{M}{\mu N})$ because we know  $M=N\mu tanhx$ and $x=\frac{\mu B}{kt}$. Is this approach correct?

Comment: That function is not called `tanh` but `\tanh` in LaTeX, use the leading backslash to great benefit. That manner of reasoning is probably also acceptable to your teacher, especially if this "$x = \mu~B/(k~T)$" business is something that you derived in class.